# HTML <select> required Attribute not working in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, validation, html5

I'm trying to implement a form with a **required** drop-down list on a VF page, as described in this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required).

If you click on the link above and run the sample, it works fine but when I try to implement it on a VF page it does not.

In my code below I have two fields of type text and select, the validation runs on the text field if it remains blank but not on the select (if the value is set to the default None).

Please advise.

```
<apex:page>
   <body>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
         <input type="text" required="true" autofocus="true"></input>
         <select required="true">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Judging by the URL (tryhtml5_select_required) this *may* be an HTML 5 feature, have you tried setting the doctype for the VF page using `<apex:page docType="html-5.0" />`?

Comment: Yes I have, same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and I've got this working now:

Instead of:

`<option value="">None</option>`

Use the following:

`<option label="Please Select" value=""></option>`

I hope this helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite weird, but Salesforce doesn't support required attribute in select. Here's what it has in console when `<option value="">None</option>` is provided:

[image]

And if you try to debug the value passed, when None option is selected by putting an alert, like so:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('selectOption').value);"/>
```

here's what the alert message says:

[image]

What's interesting is that the value and label are considered the same when no value is specified and this behavior is different for different browsers.

The workaround suggested by Vasile actually works as label and value are specified clearly and separately. You can choose to have label of your choice too:

```
<option label="None" value=""></option>
```

But unfortunately, there's no better way to handle the html requiredness without implementing  and  and they have their limitations too.